# Gem "better_errors" not working - Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'd like to use the gem "better_errors" with my rails 3.2 application, but it's still the default error page who's displayed.

In my Gemfile :

```
group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets', '>= 1.0.1'
  gem 'better_errors', '>= 0.3.2'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '>= 0.6.8'
end
```

I did a "bundle install" and then

```
bundle show better_errors
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/better_errors-0.5.0
```

Everything seems to be well configured.

I run my rails server in development environment

```
rails s -e development
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Restart your rails server..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I scratched my head for days with the same problem.  I finally e-mailed Charlie and he replied an hour or so later with my answer: "You need to be on localhost to use better_errors"

I had been developing in a Ubuntu VM on a Windows 7 host and browsing the site from Windows. Although it's a security risk, you can allow this by following the instructions here: https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors#security

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: A variation on the above solution is to put this in `config/environments/development.rb`:

    `BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '192.168.10.14'`

Comment: Aye, that's what I actually ended up doing.  Charlie also mentioned that you can use SSH port forwarding to make it appear like you are running on localhost.  This keeps the hole outside of your rails environment.

Comment: What happens when you deploy in production however? I keep running into the issue that BetterErrors is uninitialized when trying to deploy

Answer (score 3):

add line to ./config/environments/development.rb

> BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! "CLIENT_IPADDR"

and, restart rails-server

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this episode of railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel

This is my `group development` with `better_errors` gem:

```
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
end
```

You can follow these steps:

Update `better_error` gem to the last version!.

1º uninstall `current version` of `better_error` gem with command `gem uninstall better_errors`.

2º Then Remove `'>= 1.0.1'`,  `'>= 0.3.2'`, `'>= 0.6.8'` of your gem file and run the command `bundle install`

Regards!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't works. Even RailsPanel with meta_request doesn't works :-( And I don't have any config/initializers/better_errors.rb is it normal?

Comment: It makes me crazy. `bundle install` :
Using better_errors (0.6.0) 
Using debug_inspector (0.0.2) 
Using binding_of_caller (0.7.1) 
But nothing has changed

Comment: Create a new rails with `rails new myapp` command on other place and try bundle install. If with this app is working fine, you have a problem with your current app, perhaps, any gem version, rails version, ruby version...etc. Take a look to necessary dependencies of `better_errors` gem

Answer (score 1):

Can you try a bundle update? as the current version I have is 0.6.0.

Also I don't use the config/initializers/better_errors.rb file

Check in the server logs if you are not having 500 Internal Server Errors, when I've got them at the models after an ajax update I don't see the better_errors page.